# I have an issue with mysqli_fetch_assoc() and mysqli_result i posted my code below

Tags: php, jquery, function, mysqli

I need some help checking this function, thanks in advance for any help:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
     $data = array();
     $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_result ("SELECT $fields FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id"));

    print_r($data);
    die();

    return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You gonna tell us what your issue is?

Comment: well it has to do mysqli_fetch_assoc and mysqli_result, i always get this error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given. what seems to be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is returning the row pertinent to user id, then just remove other functions:

```
function user_data($user_id) {

    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int) $user_id;
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $user_id = $con->real_escape_string($user_id);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $data = $query->fetch_assoc();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Your usage of `func_get_args` doesn't make sense since you just unsetting them before usage. And take off that single quotes in your query.

Identifier quotes are backticks. Or just remove them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try with escaping the variables in the Query.
As the result it is returning null. SO the query is not executing

```
   $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_result ("SELECT "+$fields+" FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = "+$user_id+""));
```